# Shorter word for "Uncanny person"? (New Zealand english)

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title stated it's a simple question but to elaborate a bit more by giving a example...

I was watching a harmless video from YouTube via. The Short feature where two girls stated they "looked Like sisters" when they obviously did not briefly before doing a comparison video sort of thing then it cuts to one of the girls laughing where it's showing alot of the girls gum.

It wasn't really the gum laugh thing that took me off guard the whole video just felt strange and foreign to be honest as the two girl were no doubt real people but at the same time not.

TLDR: Is there a shorter word for an "uncanny person"?

Comment: IDK about NZ but it was **unreal**.

Comment: 1) Did you check out a thesaurus for synonyms of 'uncanny'? 2) can you give a sentence with a blank so we know better how you plan to use it? 3) Also, maybe reword what you want to say. Instead of "She is an [uncanny person]". say "She is [uncanny]". 4) Are you looking for something like 'weirdo' or as an adjective weird or strange? It's hard to tell from your description.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the feeling you described, I will propose:

**creepy**

From [Oxford Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/):

> causing an unpleasant feeling of fear or unease. "the creepy feelings
> one often gets in a strange house"

Comment: Yeah sort of, I thought about it and the word "Stranger" is close but I feel as if that word is more associated with an "unknown person" rather than a "uncanny person".

Comment: @Charles - Right.  "Stranger" doesn't work for what you want to express.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you mean the video or the girls are "uncanny". It is also unclear whether you are looking for a word that is (i) unique to, or (ii) would be understood in, New Zealand.

That said,

OED:

**surreal**, adj.

**Having the qualities of surrealist art; bizarre, dreamlike.**

1937   Burlington Mag. Jan. p. xiv/1   *Some ‘surreal’ influence haunts the regions of the Black Forest.*

MW

**surreal** adjective

**1: marked by the intense irrational reality of a dream**

*Players traverse surreal worlds and duke it out with sentient poker chips, demonic clowns and boxing frogs across elaborate, multistage boss battles.* — Alyse Stanley, Washington Post, 17 May 2022

Comment: Surreal is pretty close, but what I meant really was "uncanny" in the "cursed" sort of way but not in a negative "literally cursed" manner or "Dreamlike/Otherworldy" feeling. I was thinking more along the lines of a "cursed/erie" photo or video but personified and single worded.